# Integrating Jane payment system into MailerLite

Tags: integration, payment, mailerlite

I'm at a standstill. A client is looking to integrate her Jane payment system into her new MailerLite account, which my boss suggested and encouraged her to move to from her previous ActiveCampaign account. I have found no way to accomplish this as the systems don''t seem to allow for this. Is there a workaround anyone kmows of for these systems? First time working with both systems, but have been familiarized with MailerLite over the course of the last several months for this client.

Thank you,

I have scoured the internet trying to find out how anyone else has ever accomplished this after scouring both systems to see if there was any way to do this- the obvious ways (through their integration tabs) do not allow for this.